# QDesktopServices::openUrl() fails if path contains spaces (after "apt-get upgrade")

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debian

I recently saw this error on programs which used to work fine. I think that the error started appearing after I did a `sudo apt-get upgrade`, which might have upgraded the Qt libraries on my machine.

I've reproduced this error for newly created project containing this code:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("/home/sashoalm/Has Spaces.txt"));
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/sashoalm/Has Spaces.txt"));
```

This produces 2 message boxes saying the same - `/home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt: No such file or directory`. But the file exists - I've verified that, `xdg-open "/home/sashoalm/Has Spaces.txt"` works fine, for example.

Any workarounds? When did this bug happen? My OS is Debian Wheezy.

**Edit:** I checked Qt4's source code, and the relevant code is this (from qdesktopservices_x11.cpp):

```
return (QProcess::startDetached(client + QLatin1Char(' ') + QString::fromLatin1(url.toEncoded().constData())));
```

QUrl::toEncoded() returns the percent-encoded path as `file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt`. What is strange is that there were no changes in that file save updating the copyright notices since at before 2011. So it can't be a change in Qt. But the command issued by QDesktopServices::openUrl() is `xdg-open file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt`, and that doesn't work on my computer. Perhaps it used to work before, and an update to xdg-open itself broke it? Does anyone know if xdg-open should handle `file:///` with percent encoding?

Comment: Hm, strange. `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("d:\\a b\\c d.txt"));` works just fine on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

on Qt5

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/sashoalm/Has Spaces.txt"));
```

worked just fine. I was having the same problem when loading the file purely from a QUrl like the first line

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("/home/sashoalm/Has Spaces.txt"));
```

but when used the QUrl::fromLocalFile it just did the thing

Answer (score 4):

Either escape the space with \

```
QUrl("/home/sashoalm/Has\ Spaces.txt")
```

or add quotes to the path: -

```
QUrl("\"/home/sashoalm/Has Spaces\"")
```

Comment: Eh, that first backslash in the first line would be caught by the compiler, while in the second line the last symbol is a slash /" instead of \", not backslash, so it won't even compile. I tested them anyway, and they didn't work sure enough.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake about the final slash, which should be a backslash. I've corrected it here. If you use a QFileInfo object with the path, does QfileInfo::exists() return true? Good point about the compiler, you may need to put them together and escape the space with the backslash, but also escape the whole string with quotes.

Comment: See my edit, the problem has nothing to do with that, and the proposed solutions still don't work. The problem is more likely with `xdg-open`, it does not handle percent-encoded urls, and that's what QDesktopServices::openUrl() does, I looked into the source code, and I've posted the relevant part of the code. Keep in mind that even the quotes will be percent-encoded, so it will still fail. Also, I wrote that I've verified it exists already.

Comment: You wrote that you verified it exists by directly calling xdg-open, which isn't exactly the same as calling it from QDesktopServices. If the problem is with QDesktopServices, what about using QProcess instead and calling "xdg-open" with that?